# Xero Api ItemTrackingCategory throws Null Reference Error

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to set the value of TrackingCategory on an invoice Line Item.  My code is as follows:

```
                    LineItem li = new LineItem();
                    li.LineAmount = inv.LineItems[i].LineAmount;
                    li.ItemCode = inv.LineItems[i].ItemCode;
                    li.Description = inv.LineItems[i].Description;
                    li.AccountCode = inv.LineItems[i].AccountCode;
                    li.UnitAmount = inv.LineItems[i].UnitAmount;
                    var categories = inv.Categories.Where(c => c.TicketChargeLineId == inv.LineItems[i].TicketChargeLineId);
                    foreach(var c in categories)
                    {
                        if(c.Value != "")
                        {

                            ItemTrackingCategory tc = new ItemTrackingCategory();
                            tc.Name = c.Name;
                            tc.Id = c.Id;
                            tc.Option = c.Value;
                            li.Tracking.Add(tc);

                        }

                    }

                    lineItems.Add(li);
```

It errors at `li.Tracking.Add(tc)`.  It gives the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", however tc is not null.  It does show an empty Guid for OptionId.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you instantiated the "Tracking" property?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I instantiated ItemTrackingCategory.  What else should I have done?

Comment: In the line "li.Tracking.Add(tc);" - what value does the "Tracking" property have? If you haven't instantiated it as a some kind of collection, that's probably your null reference.

Comment: Great catch, that worked.  Thanks!